# Laravel 5.7: use translation strings or keys?

Tags: php, laravel, translation

It's not exactly a problem I face since I understand both ways, I'm just unsure about which one to use.

Currently I'm using translation strings with a JSON file because it was less to write.
Now I wanted to use Laravel's pluralization which i found out can only be used with translation keys.
(at least I haven't found something telling me otherwise)

So my questions are:

What should I use?
What are the advantages of using translation keys rather than translation strings?
Is it 'too much' using both ways since it's just two or three times I'd be using the pluralization?

Comment: Pluralization can be used with any string using the string helper functions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-plural

Comment: @Jerodev this only works for the english language.

Comment: So does any other Laravel pluralization implementation.

Comment: @Jerodev https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#pluralization here you can find the pluralization I mean; where you put the singular & plural sentences yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from using both.

As far as I tested, the translation using JSON file is way faster. You can test it yourself:

```php
$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i<=100000; $i++) {
    __('example.text.in.en.json.file');
}
echo microtime(true)-$t; //0.25 seconds

$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i<=100000; $i++) {
    __('validation.accepted'); // example in validation.php
}
echo microtime(true)-$t; //0.55 seconds
```

The difference is caused by the extra options you have with `key` translation (I guess).